# Swift Nested jSON Decode

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I have problem with nested json decoding. Im getting no error but response is empty { }. Down bellow is my sample json and struct.

```
{
"categories": [
{
  "ID": 130,
  "data": [
    {
      "en": [
        {
          "title": "test"
        }
      ],
      "fr": [
        {
          "title": "teste"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "lifts": [
    {
      "ID": 104,
      "data": [
        {
          "en": [
            {
              "code": "test",
              "title": "test"
            }
          ],
          "fr": [
            {
              "code": "test",
              "title": "test"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": 105,
      "data": [
        {
          "en": [
            {
              "code": "test",
              "title": "test"
            }
          ],
          "fr": [
            {
              "code": "test",
              "title": "test"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my struct

```
struct jsonResponse : Codable {

struct Categories : Codable {

    let id : Int
    let data : [LanguageData]
    let lifts : [Lifts]

    struct LanguageData : Codable {

        let en, fr : [Data]

        struct Data : Codable {

            let code : String?
            let title : String?
        }
    }

    struct LiftsData : Codable {
        let id : Int
        let data : [LanguageData]
    }
}
```

Then Im trying to decode JSON like this:

```
let lifts = try JSONDecoder().decode(jsonResponse.self, from: data)
```

But when I print lifts, i see only empty {}. Also no error message during decoding, so have no idea what can be wrong.

Comment: ok it validates now. there are many online service to help you with code generation for decoding: https://app.quicktype.io/ and others. you can also try libraries like SwiftyJson

Comment: i was deleting json before i paste here so might i delete something more and made it invalid but json which im trying to decode is valid, i did validation

Comment: also https://www.json4swift.com/ is a good one.

Comment: Its a invalid json

Comment: why is `categories` an array? when it has only one json object in it?

Comment: Does not seem to be problem with structs at all. I tried paste structs from app.quicktype.io and getting same error that im trying to decode array but found dictionary. Does not make a sense, structs are defined as dictionary.

Comment: Your `let lifts:` has a type `Lifts`, but you named the struct `LiftsData`. This code should not compile. Also in `LiftsData` your property name `id` is lowercase, but JSON returns uppercase `ID`. Considering that Codable is case-sensitive, that might be your problem